# How to do a summation in R using igraph package

Tags: r, igraph

I am trying to calculate the queue size in a network in R. For that at first I calculate the betweenness centrality of all the nodes in the network which returns a vector. For calculating the queue, I have to do a summation of all the betweenness value for all the nodes and multiply it with some other values which will be constant in my case. I have tried to use a for loop and my code is given below:

```
between <- betweenness(graphList[[1]], v=V(graphList[[1]]), directed =TRUE, weights = NULL,nobigint = TRUE, normalized = FALSE)
S <- length (between)
A <- 0
for(i in 1:length(S))
{
 A = A + sum (d * l * between [i]/(S - 1 - (d * l * between [i])) )
}
```

Now the value A returns for only the first value of between, not the entire vector. Is there any other way to calculate this? Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that when you call `length(S)` as your loop variable, you are taking the `length` of the `length` of `between`, ie if `length(between)` is `29`, `S = 29` and `length(S)` is `1`. Therefore you only get 1 loop. You can change it to:

```
for(i in 1:S)....
```

And it will work.

BUT:

All the calculations you are doing on between are vectorised, so there is no need for a loop:

```
library(igraph)
set.seed(24)
g <- random.graph.game(10, 3/10)
between <- betweenness(g)
S <- length (between)
A <- 0
d <- 0.5 #not sure what value you had
l <- 0.5 #not sure again
A <- sum((d * l * between /(S - 1 - (d * l * between)) ))
A
[1] 1.219178
```